# Computing Growth Rates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am working on a dataset for a welfare wage subsidy program, where wages per worker are structured as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(wage_1990 = c(13451.67, 45000, 10301.67, NA, NA, 
8726.67, 11952.5, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, 
NA, 9881.67, 5483.33, 12868.33, 9321.67), wage_1991 = c(13451.67, 
45000, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8750, 11952.5, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 
10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 5483.33, 12868.33, 9321.67
), wage_1992 = c(13451.67, 49500, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8750, 11952.5, 
NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, NA, 
12868.33, 9321.67), wage_1993 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8750, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 
NA, NA, 9321.67), wage_1994 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8948.33, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 
NA, NA, 9321.67), wage_1995 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8948.33, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7140, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 9881.67, 
NA, NA, 9321.67), wage_1996 = c(NA, NA, 10301.67, NA, NA, 8948.33, 
11958.33, NA, NA, 7291.67, NA, NA, 10301.67, 7303.33, NA, NA, 
9881.67, NA, NA, 9321.67)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I have tried one proposed solution, which is running this code after the one above:

```
average_growth_rate <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
        x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]
         mean(x1[-1]/x1[-length(x1)]-1)})
out <- data.frame(rowid = seq_len(nrow(df)), average_growth_rate)
out[!is.na(out$average_growth_rate),]
```

But I keep getting this error:

Error in dim(X) <- c(n, length(X)/n) : dims [product 60000] do not match the length of object [65051]

I want to do the following: 1-Create a variable showing the annual growth rate of wage for each worker or lack of thereof.

The practical issue that I am facing is that each observation is in one row and while the first worker joined the program in 1990, others might have joined in say 1993 or 1992. Therefore, is there a way to apply the growth rate for each worker depending on the specific years they worked, rather than applying a general growth formula for all observations?

My expected output for each row would be having a new column

```
      average wage growth rate
1-         15%
2-         9%
3-         12%
```

After running the following code to see descriptive statistics of my variable of interest:

```
skim(df$average_growth_rate)
```

I get the following result:

```
"Variable contains Inf or -Inf value(s) that were converted to NA.── Data Summary ────────────────────────
                           Values                      
Name                       gosi_beneficiary_growth$a...
Number of rows             3671                        
Number of columns          1                           
_______________________                                
Column type frequency:                                 
  numeric                  1                           
________________________                               
Group variables            None                        

── Variable type: numeric ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  skim_variable n_missing complete_rate  mean    sd    p0    p25   p50    p75  p100 hist 
1 data               1348         0.633   Inf   Inf    -1 -0.450     0 0.0568  
"
```

I am not sure why my mean and standard deviation values are Inf.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Good question, I have edited my post. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Could you explain how you got to the 15% for the first row?

Comment: Just a hypothetical example, not based on the data... more on how I would like the final output to look like

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

growth <- df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(key, value, -rowid) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  arrange(rowid, key) %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  mutate(yoy = value / lag(value)-1) %>% 
  summarise(average_growth_rate = mean(yoy, na.rm=T))

# A tibble: 12 x 2
   rowid average_growth_rate
   <int>               <dbl>
 1     1           0        
 2     2           0.05     
 3     3           0        
 4     6           0.00422  
 5     7           0.0000813
 6    10           0.00354  
 7    13           0        
 8    14           0        
 9    17           0        
10    18           0        
11    19           0        
12    20           0
```

---

And just to highlight that all these 0s are expected, here the dataframe:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  wage_1990 wage_1991 wage_1992 wage_1993 wage_1994 wage_1995 wage_1996
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1    13452.    13452.    13452.       NA        NA        NA        NA 
2    45000     45000     49500        NA        NA        NA        NA 
3    10302.    10302.    10302.    10302.    10302.    10302.    10302.
4       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 
5       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 
6     8727.     8750      8750      8750      8948.     8948.     8948.
```

where you see that e.g. for the first row, there was no growth nor any decline. The second row, there was a slight increase in between the second and the third year, but it was 0 for the first and second. For the third row, again absolutely no change. Etc...

---

Also, finally, to add these results to the initial dataframe, you would do e.g.

```
df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  left_join(growth)
```

---

And just to answer the performance question, here a benchmark (where I changed akrun's data.frame call to a tibble call to make sure there is no difference coming from this). All functions below correspond to creating the growth rates, not merging back to the original dataframe.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(cj(), akrun(), akrun2())
Unit: microseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
     cj() 5577.301 5820.501 6122.076 5988.551 6244.301 10646.9   100   c
  akrun()  998.301 1097.252 1559.144 1160.450 1212.552 28704.5   100 a  
 akrun2() 2033.801 2157.101 2653.018 2258.052 2340.702 34143.0   100  b
```

`base R` is the clear winner in terms of performance.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! 
Is there an efficient way of applying this to 000's of rows/observations?

Comment: How long does it take? You could try akrun's base R answer or a `data.table` version if this is really not fast enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like your intuitive code as well!

In regards to the time, I currently don't have access to my PC at work, so been relying on an older slower computer, thanks again!

Comment: I have updated my answer with a quick benchmark. As you can see, @akrun's first answer is the best so far.

Comment: Hahaha... I find this interesting, thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` with `apply`.  Loop over the  rows  with `MARGIN = 1`, remove the `NA` elements ('x1'), get the `mean` of the ratio of the current and previous element

```
average_growth_rate <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
        x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]
         mean(x1[-1]/x1[-length(x1)]-1)})
out <- data.frame(rowid = seq_len(nrow(df)), average_growth_rate)
out[!is.na(out$average_growth_rate),]
#    rowid average_growth_rate
#1      1       0.00000000000
#2      2       0.05000000000
#3      3       0.00000000000
#6      6       0.00422328325
#7      7       0.00008129401
#10    10       0.00354038282
#13    13       0.00000000000
#14    14       0.00000000000
#17    17       0.00000000000
#18    18       0.00000000000
#19    19       0.00000000000
#20    20       0.00000000000
```

---

Or using `tapply/stack`

```
na.omit(stack(tapply(as.matrix(df), row(df), FUN = function(x) 
     mean(head(na.omit(x), -1)/tail(na.omit(x), -1) -1))))[2:1]
```

Comment: Thanks, check my updated post as I am still having some issues.

Comment: @maa425 thanks, with your example, I am not getting any error.  Can you please update with an example that shows the issue

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response!
Yes, this is the error I am getting:
"Error in dim(X) <- c(n, length(X)/n) : dims [product 60000] do not match the length of object [65051]"

I ran the same code as the one shown in the post.

Comment: @maa425 If you could update with a small example that gives the same error, it would be easier to debug.  Do you have any rows with only `NA` elements?

Comment: No, I don't have any rows where the entire unit of analysis has NA elements. However, it is possible to have NA in some columns such as, "retirement date" if say the person has not retired yet.

I have updated my post with more details.

Comment: @maa425 in your new example, there are rows with only NA alone.  What do you want to do with those rows

Comment: I am not sure how to deal with such rows when running my models...would appreciate your support. The results of my models currently do not make sense because of how I coded the "average_growth_rate." For instance, I am certain that no one in my data should have an average wage growth -.45, as shown by a variable in the 25th perentile.

Comment: @maa425 if you are okay with removing those rows, `df1 <- df[rowSums(is.na(df)) < ncol(df),]`

Comment: Thanks! The code works w/out errors; however, still has not resolved the odd, "average_growth_rate" values...based on descriptive statistics.